# How to store the windows OS NAME of remotes servers listed on a txt file

Tags: batch-file

I am looking to store the windows OS NAME of remotes servers listed on a txt file called servers.txt, into another txt file, called osversion.txt.

I have a TXT file with a content like this:

> ```
> HOSTNAME1
> HOSTNAME2
> ........
> HOSTNAMEn
> ```

I am writing a script with the following line that should do the job after getting the hostname on the variable HOSTNAME:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (servers.txt) do (
   SET HOSTNAME=%%A
   "C:\Oper\PsTools\psexec.exe" \\HOSTNAME -u %USER% -p %PASSWORD% cmd /K systeminfo | find "OS Name" >> \\%LOCALSERVER%\C$\Users\%MYUSER%\Desktop\osversion.txt
)
```

However my osversion.txt is empty and the cmd window

Comment: You need `delayedexpansion` to start with.

Comment: There is `%%A`, which you can use. You assign it to a variable. You don't use either `%%A` (`... \\%%A ...`) or the variable (`... \\!HOSTNAME! ...`), but a fixed string (`... \\HOSTNAME ...`) instead.

Comment: @Stephan: Thank you. I changed it to !HOSTNAME! :<<br>> "C:\Oper\PsTools\psexec.exe" \\!HOSTNAME! .......<<br>><<br>>
But it only gets the OS NAME of the first server on the file. After that it looks like it gets stucked somewhere: <<br>><<br>>

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...<<br>>
PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely<<br>>
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich<<br>>
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com<<br>>
<<br>>
Starting cmd on STG-CGSG01-01...n STG-CGSG01-01...<<br>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, have you tried using WMIC?

Here's an example:

```bat
@Set "LIST=MyComputers.txt"
@Set "USER=MyUserName"
@Set "PASSWORD=MyPassword"
@Set "RESULTS=MyFile.csv"

@"%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe" /FailFast:On /Node:"@%LIST%" /Output:"%RESULTS%" /Password:"%PASSWORD%" /User:"%USER%" OS Get Caption,OSArchitecture,Version /Format:CSV
```

Just propagate the values between the `=` and the closing `"` on each of the first four lines, with your actual strings.

*Please open up a Command Prompt window and enter `wmic /?` to begin reading its usage information and to refine the above example to meet your needs.*

Comment: Thanks! It worked. However I had to do @"WMIC.exe" ........   since it didn't work with the %__APPDIR__% (nor with any other PATH). How can I also write something for the servers that are not reachable (write something like "ERROR" ou "NOT_REACHABLE")? I have put wrong server names just to see what it writes into the file and the file is empty.

Comment: @pdpereira, I have corrected the location in my answer, as I had forgotten to include the parent directory for the WMIC executable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support guys. It is working fine @Compo. :)